# How can display these elements in line?

Tags: html, css

I have this site:

http://www.les-toiles.co/shop/amandine-dress/

I put a picture to understand better what I  want.I want to position these sights integral to be in line with the "in stock".

[image]

This is code HTML:

```
<div class="single_variation_wrap" style="">
    <div class="single_variation">
         <p class="stock in-stock">Only 2 left in stock</p>
    </div>
    <div class="variations_button add-cart">
        <div class="cart-number">
            <span></span>
            <div class="quantity">
                <input type="number" step="1" name="quantity" value="1" title="Quantity" class="input-text qty text" size="4" min="1" max="2">
           </div>
       </div>
       <button type="submit" class="button single_add_to_cart_button alt btn-block">
           <i class="icon-cart2"></i>
           Add to cart              
       </button>
    </div>

    <input type="hidden" name="add-to-cart" value="1726">
    <input type="hidden" name="product_id" value="1726">
    <input type="hidden" name="variation_id" value="1922">
</div>
```

How can I resolve this with CSS?

I tried to add this CSS code, but unfortunately not working

```
.cart-number {float:left;display:inline-block;}
```

Comment: You tried nothing so far, so see `float`.

Comment: I tried to add float: left but did not know exactly where to do that

Comment: Specify an exact width for `.cart-number` then use `float: left` for both `.cart-number` and `.single_add_to_car_button`

Comment: I add this code .cart-number{width:60px;float:left;}
.single_add_to_car_button{float:left;} but not working.

Comment: Also after reviewing the link provided on Chrome and Safari, it seems that the 'add to cart' button is already aligned horizontally with the 'quantity' box..

Comment: Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is not just an easy quick thing that you can get. There are much more things that need to changed. Let me see how far can I explain. Refer the attached images. For this, you should use the 'Chrome Dev Toolbar' or Firebug of Firefox, so that it helps.

First, the **div** block of your **Wishlist** button is completely outside the **FORM** element. So you can't make it inline, unless you move it inside the **FORM** element. See the 1st Image.

[image]

Now I have moved the DIV block of your Wishlist button inside the FORM element and have modified CSS for many classes and DIVs, definitely as INLINE, for demonstration. You need to really work hard to put this as modular as possible. I am sure you'll figure that out. In the next image, You'll see the effect as you wanted and see the CIRCLED section for the added or edited CSS code

[image]

Comment: For better clarity of my comments and code, open the attached images in a new tab/window

Answer (score 0):

Add `display:inline-block;` to **both** `.button` and `.cart-number`. It tells the elements to position themselves on the same line, and hopefully with this method you should't need to use `float`.

Comment: So should it be? .class{display:inline-block;}
.cart-number{display:inline-block;float:left;width:60px;}

Comment: @Cristi whoops sorry I meant to type .button, not .class

Comment: I corrected and still nothing happens. Try to add code with firebug and you'll see that nothing changes...:(

Comment: @Cristi I followed your link in Safari and the buttons seem to be displayed inline for me? Also be sure to specify a width for both classes

Comment: Put please the code exactly as you wrote.
In that file you added, woocommerce.css? Thanks